# How to deploy WCF services using INNO setup?

Tags: wcf, inno-setup

Actually i created MSI package for WCF service using Advance Installer.
**Now i want to create MSI or exe package for WCF service Using **INNO SETUP****
I am using Inno Script Studio 5.5.3.
I am beginner in Inno setup, now only i installed the Inno setup application,So i don't aware of anything.
I am having dll which is created with the help of WCF service.Then I created window service application with reference of dll, then created exe package with service application.

**How can i create MSI or exe package using INNO setup.
It is possible to create setup with the help of WCF service dll alone.
Else if i need to use exe of windows service application, to create msi or exe package for INNO Setup .How it is possible?
Please give me some sample application (or) steps to proceed for INNO setup..**

Regards,
Lokesh.J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd follow [`this post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1450051/960757), the InnoSetup script for installing such service might look like this (just copy and paste it into the InnoSetup code editor and save it somewhere on your harddrive):

```
[Setup]
AppName=App Name
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\Folder Name

[Files]
Source: "C:\SomeFolder\YourService.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\YourService.exe"; Parameters: "--install"

[UninstallRun]
Filename: "{app}\YourService.exe"; Parameters: "--uninstall"
```

Comment: Hi,I followed your step.thank you.But it doesn't put entry in Window service, i searched the window services with my provided display name,no entry i can found,so i cant start the service. How to put entry in window services(services.msc), and i have to start it.Please reply

Comment: That's what the `ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper` implemented in the linked post should do.

Comment: I did the above method, still it doesn't put entry in window services. Though i am new to INNO Script, i dono how to create package, based on some forums i created a package, which contains the following things i posted very next comments pls check .

Comment: [Run]
Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}";Parameters: "--install"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,{#StringChange(MyAppName, '&', '&&')}}"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent
[UninstallRun]
Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Parameters: "--uninstall" In {#MyAPPExeName}" do i need to provide my exe name. instead of #MyAPPExeName? Can i get any sample application to achieve this task?

Comment: I assume that yes. However, I don't know what you mean with sample application. Script which I have in my post just copy and paste into the InnoSetup script editor, save it somewhere. Modify paths and file names there according to your needs (their meaning is obvious) and press F9 what build your setup and run it in debugger. Before you do so, try to install your service from command line (try to check if you're able to un/install it using those `--install` and `--uninstall` parameters).

Comment: Thank you. its working fine now..can i know how to assign localip in baseaddress of appconfig file?

Comment: Sorry, that's what is out of scope of this question. If my post resolved this question, you should [`accept it`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/179541) and ask this as a separate question, but I think you're looking for [`this way`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6937853/wcf-service-endpoints-vs-host-base-address). Thanks!