# "Service metadata may not be accessible" impossible to run my WCF service

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, web-config

Good afternoon,

I create a database and then add a WCF service but when I want to run my WCF I have this error "Service metadata may not be accessible".

The problem is that I follow the steps of another topic from this website in order to solve my error, but anyway there is still this restriction and I can't have access to my WCF.

Here is my Web config I tried to modify with the other topic about the same error but do you see any mistakes which can't make my WCF impossible to run ?

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="metadataBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
      <services>
        <service name="Service3.Service3" behaviorConfiguration="metadataBehavior">
          <endpoint
              address=""
              binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="jsonpBinding"
              contract="Service3.IService3"/>
          <endpoint
              address="mex"
              binding="mexHttpBinding"
              contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        </service>
      </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

I tried a lot of changes, like even if I put a localhost address in the first endpoint there is still this error when I run my WCF.

I tried to change the different binding too but nothing changes error still appears ... Need help please !

Thanks for your answers

Edit: I tried to make changes but the error is still here. Here my new Web config file:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="metadataBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
      <services>
        <service name="Service3.Service3" behaviorConfiguration="metadataBehavior">
          <endpoint 
              address="http://localhost:7488/"
              binding="basicHttpBinding" 
              contract="HostService.IService3" />
          <endpoint
              address=""
              binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="jsonpBinding"
              contract="Service3.IService3"/>
          <endpoint
              address="mex"
              binding="mexHttpBinding"
              contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        </service>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:7488/Service3.svc" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Are you hosting in IIS?

Comment: No because I tried to host with IIS earlier today to fix my problem but nothing happened so ... (I am really a beginner with all of this..)

Comment: You need to add a base address to your config ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6937853/wcf-service-endpoints-vs-host-base-address

Comment: Should I only add the base adress or modify address and bindings too ?

Comment: And should I add this line in my <behavior> :
<serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" /> ?

Because I added the base adress which is the one from my .svc file but the error still  occurs ... :( But thanks for your help I need Base adress for later anyway

Comment: If you're not hosting in IIS then you won't have a svc file. You only need one to host in IIS.

Comment: I really don't know how to solve it I'm stuck ...